# Dynamic tables from UDF in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, dynamic-tables

how can i decide this problem?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDataById] ()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(500)
  DECLARE @j INT
  SET @query=N'select * from catalog'
  EXEC sp_executesql @query
  RETURN @j
END
```

When I try to exec this one: `select dbo.GetDataById()`

I get an error message:

> Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? That function makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

From [this post](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#UDF) by Erland Sommarskog, SQL Server MVP :

> you cannot use dynamic SQL from
>   used-defined functions written in
>   T-SQL. This is because you are not
>   permitted do anything in a UDF that
>   could change the database state (as
>   the UDF may be invoked as part of a
>   query). Since you can do anything from
>   dynamic SQL, including updates, it is
>   obvious why dynamic SQL is not
>   permitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dynamically-created SQL from within a function. You have to use a stored procedure for that.

But in your case I don't see why you even put your query into a variable anyway.

Comment: this is only example..
i have too much long request (more than 4000 symbols), more than 2000 tables in DB, and a lot of queries are indefinitive, most of them generates on the fly..

Comment: Well, then you need stored procedures. *Unless* you also need to join the results and use them in `SELECT` statements. Then you're either at a loss or in for some really ugly solutions.